# WCF UDP Security Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I have create a custom binding with the following settings and hosted it in my application.

- URL address with "soap.udp://....."
- BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement
- UdpTransportBindingElement

All works well. I can send messages and receive message on multiple receiver via multicasting.

However, I want to add security (encryption and signing) to the binding but I wasn't sure if it is possible.

I can't seems to find any information regarding UDP binding and security.
I can only find information on TCP and http with security as shown in his article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730305(v=vs.110).aspx)

Anyone knows whether:
1) Can udp binding includes security binding element?
2) Which security binding element is applicable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately according to MS, udpBinding does not support either message or transport level security.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879(v=vs.110).aspx

You will need to handle the encryption/decryption of types yourself, which will probably mean changing your service contract definition.